# java.security.InvalidAlgorithmParameterException: null

Tags: java, spring, ssl, tls1.2

I've run into this exception when trying to run Spring Boot application with SSL certificate. The app is running inside Kubernetes as Docker container.

The key issue is that the description of the excpetion is **null**.

Has anyone run into such issue?

**UPDATE1** - I've based my Dockerfile on [`openjdk:8-jre-alpine`](https://hub.docker.com/r/library/openjdk/tags/). I've revert 
back to `openjdk:8u111-jre-alpine` and the error disapear. I still don't know what the cause of the error.

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: java.security.InvalidAlgorithmParameterException
        at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.checkThrown(Handshaker.java:1476) ~[na:1.8.0_121]
        at sun.security.ssl.SSLEngineImpl.checkTaskThrown(SSLEngineImpl.java:535) ~[na:1.8.0_121]
        at sun.security.ssl.SSLEngineImpl.readNetRecord(SSLEngineImpl.java:813) ~[na:1.8.0_121]
        at sun.security.ssl.SSLEngineImpl.unwrap(SSLEngineImpl.java:781) ~[na:1.8.0_121]
        at javax.net.ssl.SSLEngine.unwrap(SSLEngine.java:624) ~[na:1.8.0_121]
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SecureNioChannel.handshakeUnwrap(SecureNioChannel.java:459) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.6.jar!/:8.5.6]
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SecureNioChannel.handshake(SecureNioChannel.java:232) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.6.jar!/:8.5.6]
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1387) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.6.jar!/:8.5.6]
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.6.jar!/:8.5.6]
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142) [na:1.8.0_121]
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617) [na:1.8.0_121]
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.6.jar!/:8.5.6]
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [na:1.8.0_121]
Caused by: java.security.ProviderException: java.security.InvalidAlgorithmParameterException
        at sun.security.ec.ECKeyPairGenerator.generateKeyPair(ECKeyPairGenerator.java:147) ~[sunec.jar:1.8.0_121]
        at java.security.KeyPairGenerator$Delegate.generateKeyPair(KeyPairGenerator.java:703) ~[na:1.8.0_121]
        at sun.security.ssl.ECDHCrypt.<init>(ECDHCrypt.java:65) ~[na:1.8.0_121]
        at sun.security.ssl.ServerHandshaker.setupEphemeralECDHKeys(ServerHandshaker.java:1431) ~[na:1.8.0_121]
        at sun.security.ssl.ServerHandshaker.trySetCipherSuite(ServerHandshaker.java:1229) ~[na:1.8.0_121]
        at sun.security.ssl.ServerHandshaker.chooseCipherSuite(ServerHandshaker.java:1026) ~[na:1.8.0_121]
        at sun.security.ssl.ServerHandshaker.clientHello(ServerHandshaker.java:741) ~[na:1.8.0_121]
        at sun.security.ssl.ServerHandshaker.processMessage(ServerHandshaker.java:224) ~[na:1.8.0_121]
        at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.processLoop(Handshaker.java:1026) ~[na:1.8.0_121]
        at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker$1.run(Handshaker.java:966) ~[na:1.8.0_121]
        at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker$1.run(Handshaker.java:963) ~[na:1.8.0_121]
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_121]
        at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker$DelegatedTask.run(Handshaker.java:1416) ~[na:1.8.0_121]
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SecureNioChannel.tasks(SecureNioChannel.java:407) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.6.jar!/:8.5.6]
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SecureNioChannel.handshakeUnwrap(SecureNioChannel.java:467) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.6.jar!/:8.5.6]
        ... 7 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.security.InvalidAlgorithmParameterException: null
        at sun.security.ec.ECKeyPairGenerator.generateECKeyPair(Native Method) ~[sunec.jar:1.8.0_121]
        at sun.security.ec.ECKeyPairGenerator.generateKeyPair(ECKeyPairGenerator.java:128) ~[sunec.jar:1.8.0_121]
        ... 21 common frames omitted
```

Comment: Not an actual answer but I remember seeing in the jre changelog that they removed old certificates from sun.security. Try to look into this (and consider importing an external crypto lib).

Comment: yes, saw that too but I don't think the certificate uses any of those. Also the strange thing is the null in the exception message.

Comment: I think they removed some resources that were in the JRE. Which means that the service loader used by sun.security cannot find the class/service/whatever it needed anymore. I'm sorry I'm not that well java.security-savvy but from my understanding, The Cipher can only use algorithms if there is a SecurityProvider to provide the adequate algorithm class. I know common JREs have a default provider. I know bouncyCastle brings another one. But maybe your JRE doesn't (or have a default SecurityProvider that doesn't have the algo you need)

Comment: Have you had any success resolving this? I have a very similar setup. My certificate that is failing is a self signed one that i generated.

Comment: Not yet. I've open JDK bug maybe they will find a solution.

Comment: I was able to get the container to start correctly (and work) in macOS today but the build failed on my build server (ubuntu) they were both using the same base image version c017141bdaa8 and I logged into the containers and they are both running 8u121

Ticket For reference https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8177885

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I opened an issue for this on docker-openjdk's github, and it seems to be an issue with the supported eliptic curves in
openjdk/jdk/src/share/classes/sun/security/ssl/SupportedEllipticCurvesExtension.java

https://github.com/docker-library/openjdk/issues/115

The fix was merged into 8.131.11-r2 of openjdk-alpine